# bot discord slash command erorr with code

Tags: discord, command, bots, slash

module.exports = {
name: "odrzuć",
description: "Odrzuca podanie.",
userPermissions: [`MANAGE_MESSAGES`],
botPermissions: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],

```
run: async (client, discord, message, args, interaction) => {
    let wyniki = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get("1003692442723287052");
    
    let user = interaction.guild.member.cache.get(args[0]) || interaction.mentions.members.first();
    if(!user) return interaction.channel.send(`Nie podałeś użytkownika!`)

    interaction.reply({ content: "`[ ✔️ ]\` Odrzucono podanie pomyślnie!", ephemeral: true });

    interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [{ 
        title: "ODRZUĆ",
        description: `\`[ ✔️ ]\` Twoje podanie zostało rozpatrzone negatywnie!\n\n\`[ ✔️ ]\` Po więcej informacji skontaktuj się z: <@${interaction.user.id}>`,
        color: "RANDOM"
    }] });

    wyniki.send({ embeds: [{
        title: "REKRUTACJA",
        color: "RANDOM",
        description: `Gracz ${user} nie przeszedł rekrutacji!\nOsoba rekrutująca: ${interaction.user.tag}`
    }] });
},
```

};

Comment: where is the error in the code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.